# Are there any torrent clients allowing you to choose one file from a list?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I currently use uTorrent but I need to be able to choose one file to download instead of all the available files in a folder. I can't seem to find one Play.  Any way to achieve this?

OS: 4.1.1
Samsung S3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [aTorrent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobilityflow.torrent), which has the possibility of selecting which files to download. Just change to the File tab and use the checkboxes.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do the ads drain the battery? Is the pro version worth it?

Comment: The battery drain from the ads is insignificant compared to the drain from the torrents themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I use [tTorrent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.tagsoft.ttorrent.lite).

When you open a torrent, an `Add torrent` dialog pops up. Click on the `Select files` button, and you can check / uncheck the files that you want to download.

Comment: Data limit sucks.